# iPad development in assembly

Tags: assembly, ipad

Instead of C/C++/Objective-C, is it possible to write parts of an ipad application in raw assembly?

Comment: +1... i don't care how doomed to failure your mission is, anyone who tries to write stuff in asm gets props from me. But doesn't King Steve forbid the use of any language or interpreter apart from what you have listed?

Comment: C is just portable assembly anyway, so just use C.

Comment: Write some assembly code to do some third party analytics!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anon didn't ask if it was acceptable to submit such an application to the App Store, only if it were possible to write parts in assembler.

I don't see why not. As long as you know the calling conventions and the toolchain includes an assembler, have at it. Especially if you write your assembler in the context of a C function, in a .c file, using the __asm__ GCC extensions, you probably couldn't tell from looking at the object files anyway.

Comment: +1: Inline assembly should be fine - many developers must presumably already be using this for things like VFP and NEON on the ARM CPU.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, but it's <strike>illegal</strike> [against the EULA](http://daringfireball.net/2010/04/iphone_agreement_bans_flash_compiler):

> 3.3.1 — Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs. **Applications must be originally written in Objective-C, C, C++, or JavaScript** as executed by the iPhone OS WebKit engine, and only code written in C, C++, and Objective-C may compile and directly link against the Documented APIs (e.g., Applications that link to Documented APIs through an intermediary translation or compatibility layer or tool are prohibited).

Comment: gcc supports inline assembly though ... does C + inline asembly not count as C?

Comment: @shoosh: No, but it is illegal to break a contract.

Comment: It is not illegal to "break a contract", and I wish that people would stop bringing up this hyperbole on every potential EULA "violation" on SO.

Comment: @coxymla Exactly. They also assume that the EULA will stand up in court anyway. Which as we know from many previous examples they often do not.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new today.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license_agreement#Enforceability_of_EULAs_in_the_United_States